# Reading .gif files from text file

Tags: java

So I'm at a bit of a loss, I'm aware of how to read and write data to and from a text file in Java, however, I've been asked to read the name of some gifs for a project from a text file and add them to my program.

The test code we're given to give us an idea of what to do is:

```
ArrayList<String> cardStrings = new ArrayList<>();

        cardStrings.add("3h.gif");
        cardStrings.add("tc.gif");
        cardStrings.add("js.gif");
        cardStrings.add("4d.gif");
        cardTable.cardDisplay(cardStrings);
```

The 3h, tc etc are the names of the gifs as you can probably guess already (in this case they're playing cards. 
The text file I'm trying to read this data from is structured in a way such as:

```
value
suite
value
suite
value
suite
etc..
```

So essentially I need to read in the first two lines, put them into a temp variable and put a ".gif" String on at the end, then add that set of Strings to my Array to load the card.. I think?

I originally tried something along these lines:

```
public void loadCards() throws IOException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(file path));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    int pairs = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    for (int i = 0; i< pairs-1; i++) {
        String Value = s.nextLine();
        String Suite = s.nextLine();
    }
    s.close();
}
```

I thought this might be somewhere close but I'm not sure..

Any help would be great.

Comment: What have you tried and how does it fail?

Comment: You already exactly said what you need to do. So why not read the file line by line? [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and [FileReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You want to encapsulate that discrete bit of work into a function and hand back the results.  I would suggest:

```
public ArrayList<String> loadCards() throws IOException {
  ...
  return list;
}
```

Inside your for loop, you have a value that is the base name of your gif, right?  So `value + ".gif"` is the filename you want.  Just add that to the list inside your loop.  As a best-practice, use lower-cased names for your variables, so `value` and `suite`, not `Value` and `Suite`.

Answer (score 0):

if I have read this correctly, what I assume is some course assignment has asked you to read file names from a file in java and add the file names to a string Array.

to clarify, this is to read the path of the image and not the image itself?

I would write a couple of classes, like below:

```
public enum CardType {


    H("H"),C("C"),S("S"),D("D");

    private final String code;

    CardType(String code){
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode(){
        return code;
    }


    public static CardType findByCode(String code) throws NotFoundException{
        for (CardType x : CardType.values()){
            if(x.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(code)){
                return x;
            }
        }
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
}


public class Gif {


    private String value;
    private CardType suit;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public CardType getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public void setSuit(CardType suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object gif){
        if(gif instanceof Gif){
            return ((Gif) gif).getValue().equals(getValue());
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return getValue().hashCode();
    }
}

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class LoadGifFiles {


    private Set<Gif> loadedFiles = new LinkedHashSet<Gif>();


    public void printList(){
        loadedFiles.stream().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
    }


    public void loadFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();
            Integer lineCount = 0;

            Gif currentGif = new Gif();
            while (line != null) {
                lineCount++;
                if(lineCount % 2 == 0){
                    try {
                        currentGif.setSuit(CardType.findByCode(line));
                        loadedFiles.add(currentGif);
                    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                       System.out.println("suite not known :"+line);
                    }

                }
                else {
                    currentGif = new Gif();
                    currentGif.setValue(line);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will not work because there is no CardType.values() method